# Angular 6: Update view once data is changed in service

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have multiple components side bar and view and a service. On click of side bar element component is shown. Once data in component added on service a check sign with ngClass should be on side bar. But it when data is added on service sign checked is not done dynamically when i am clicking on sidebar then only it is showing on side bar.

```html
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv': globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(1)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(1)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(1)" (click)="showForm('PAN')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(1)==true}">1</span>
      PAN
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(3)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(2)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(2)" (click)="showForm('Aadhaar')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(2)==true}">2</span>
      Aadhaar
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(3)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(3)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(3)" (click)="showForm('Basic Details')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(3)==true}">3</span>
      Basic Details
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(4)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(4)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(4)" (click)="showForm('Address')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(4)==true}">4</span>
      Address
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(5)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(5)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(5)" (click)="showForm('Regulatory Info')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(5)==true}">5</span>
      Regulatory Info
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(6)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(6)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(6)" (click)="showForm('Segments')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(6)==true}">6</span>
      Segments
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(7)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(7)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(7)" (click)="showForm('Document Upload')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(7)==true}">7</span>
      Document Upload
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(8)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(8)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(8)" (click)="showForm('Brokerage')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(8)==true}">8</span>
      Brokerage
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(9)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(9)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(9)" (click)="showForm('Review')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(9)==true}">9</span>
      Review
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-layout"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv':  globalArray.getStageArrayEnabled(10)==false, 'active':globalArray.getStageArrayHighlight(10)==true}">
    <p class="font-type" [ngClass]="getSidebarClass(10)" (click)="showForm('Televerification')">
      <span class="padd_align" [ngClass]="{'checked': globalArray.getStageArrayHide(10)==true}">10</span>
      Televerification
    </p>
  </div>
```

Please help me If possible.

Answer (score 0):

- Fast implementation solution: You could move data from service to components.
  Data can be shared between components with @Input, @Output, EventEmitter and 
  other ways depending of expectations and logic.
- Slow implementation solution: User redux and central state with data on one place.

Comment: I have already done with service and observable data is  comming on component but not updating the view.